# How to press/type function keys using cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

In my cypress test, i'm currently doing automation testing on a webpage (https://kitchen.planner.ikea.com/planner/#/gb/en/planner?startFromScratch=true) and I do have a special debug function that I trigger by doing CTRL (left) + F1 and then ALT + F12. (You can try it yourself :) )

However when I use cypress by doing:

```
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { ctrlKey: true, keyCode: 112, which: 112 })
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { altKey: true, keyCode: 123, which: 123 })
```

it passes the test but when looking at the browser, it does not trigger the debug function

My question is how can I use CTRL + F1 and then ALT + F12 using Cypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I could use [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) and it was as easy as adding this line to the code:

```
cy.realPress(['Control', 'F1'])
cy.realPress(['Alt', 'F12'])
```